# Print Linked lists with Structs

Tags: c

I got an homework assignment where I need to fill up all the functions.
Now when I get into the 3rd print, I get an error that ptr ( variable ) cannot access the data ( before he could? )

I tried printing the values before sending them to the function and see what it gets and it get the right name but the in the function something is messed up

Struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[32];
    char surname[32];
    char id[32];
    char position[64];
    int salary;
} EmployeeData;

typedef struct tEmployeeNode {
    EmployeeData data;
    struct tEmployeeNode *next;
} EmployeeNode;
```

Array with all the data:

```
    EmployeeData data[4] = {
    { "John","Silver","200011123", "Mutineer", 3000 },
    { "David","Livesey","122233345", "Doctor", 7000 },
    { "Jim","Hawkins","201072716", "Cabin Boy", 1000 },
    { "John","Trelawney","122233444", "Squire", 200 } };
```

Creating Node

```
EmployeeNode *createEmployeeNode(EmployeeData data) {
    EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeData));
    temp->data = data; 
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Creating a linked list function

```
EmployeeNode *createListOfEmployees(EmployeeData *arr, int size) {
    int i;
    EmployeeNode *head, *ptr;
    EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeData));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->data = arr[0];
    temp->next = NULL;
    head = temp;
    ptr = head;
    for (i =1; i < size; i++) {
        temp = createEmployeeNode(arr[i]);
        if (ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        else {
            ptr->next = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

main printf function :

```
void printListOfEmployees(EmployeeNode *head) {
    EmployeeNode *ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printEmployee(ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

inside printf function :

```
void printEmployee(EmployeeData e) {
    printf("%s %s %s %s %d\n", e.name, e.surname, e.id, e.position, e.salary);
}
```

Here is where I'm actually calling the functions

```
    EmployeeNode *head = createListOfEmployees(data, 4);
    printf("Employees of the Espaniola Team:\n\n");
    printListOfEmployees(head);
```

The result should be:
a. all the array node should be in the Struct with a linked list to the next node and print everything in the right order.
Mainly my problem is that I lose "Jim Hawkins" and couldn't figure why.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `EmployeeNode *temp = (EmployeeNode *)malloc(sizeof(EmployeeData));` does not look very connect, it would rather be `EmployeeNode *temp =malloc(sizeof(*temp));`

Comment: You forgot to post the function that call those functions as well as `createEmployeeNode`. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: @SouravGhosh it's 2 different structs, in the way you suggested I get an error

Comment: @Jabberwocky - added, thanks :)

Comment: Hint: your `createListOfEmployees` function is overly complicated and wrong.

Comment: what do you mean? I have to print the linked list and not just the array itself..

Comment: The `createListOfEmployees` is wrong, there are bugs. You need to debug this, or better rewrite it from scratch. Make it simpler. Complicated code more difficult to debug than simple code.

Comment: Well I can't see the problem there.. can you please point me to the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192947/discussion-between-jabberwocky-and-yakir-malka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct body of `createListOfEmployees` function (without error check for brevity):

```
EmployeeNode *head= NULL;
EmployeeNode *previousnode = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  EmployeeNode *newnode = createEmployeeNode(arr[i]);
  if (previousnode != NULL)
    previousnode->next = newnode;
  else
    head = newnode;

  previousnode = newnode;
}

return head;
```

Keep it simple.